# How can I solve this problem with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, onclick

I want to call a Javascript function when the user clicks a button, but the function is inside a condition.
Here is the HTML:

```html
<button id="demo" onclick="myFunction">Hello</button>
```

And here is the Javascript function:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
if (x == "Hello")
  function myFunction {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Good morning";
  }
```

When I click on the button nothing happens. If I delete the *if* statement, the function work, but I want it to be into a condition.
Can you help me in solving this stupid problem?

Comment: You probably want `x.textContent == "Hello"`. There is a lot wrong here…

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to change your function to something like this

```
function myFunction (){
   var x = document.getElementById("demo");
   if (x.innerHTML == "Hello"){
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Good morning";
   }
}
```

Comment: It's better to call  `var x = document.getElementById("demo");` outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here:

1. You forgot to add the parenthesis to the function

```
    <button id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">Hello</button>
```

2. Here x is the Button object and not it's inner text. Thus you use innerHTML to get the text and then compare.

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
    if (x == "Hello"){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Good morning";
      }
    }
```